# SSRS 2005 Matrix and border styles when exporting to XLS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, styles

The Matrix in SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services 2005) seems to have issues with certain the border styles when exporting to XLS (but not PDF or web view; maybe other formats, not sure?).

For example: Create a matrix and set the Matrix border style to Black Solid 1px, but all 4 of the cells to have a border style of Black None 1px. When viewed via the ASP.NET control, it looks correct. But after export to XLS, it creates borders around all of the header cells (column and row headers, and the top left cell), and even the right most data column. But all the cells in the middle of the report correctly have no border set.

Update:

If the Matrix borders are set to None, then the borders on the cells don't show up in XLS. So, how do you set an outer border around the Matrix, but not have it apply the 'all sides' border to every cell that touches the edge of the Matrix when exported to Excel?

Comment: I tried setting the border style on the Matrix itself to not have a border. But that still didn't fix this bug. Why is it setting a cell border around each cell that only touches the outter cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SSRS 2005 Excel rendering. I've been able to fix this by explicitly setting all sides of the matrix BorderStyle property (Left, Right, Top, Bottom) to Solid.

Also, when you do this, it seems like setting the BorderStyle.Default property to Solid or None doesn't matter. The value explicitly set for the other sides overrides that Default value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while exporting it to xls. but here is a cool trick to solve this....!
Use custom formating in borders...solved